# Identity to skip duplicates from other column in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

How do I make Identity skip duplicate values from 2nd column?

I am doing this:

```
create table dic_nodes
(
ID                      BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1),
nodes                   VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO dic_nodes
SELECT nodes FROM nodes_list
```

Problem is, nodes values are numbers and I have too of them. How do I make identity function skip an increment everytime they are equal?

Comment: Why are "numbers" being stored in a `VARCHAR` column?  Choose an appropriate column data type!

Comment: @DMason He does. That is not a number but an alphanumeric code he is generating.

Comment: @TomTom, based on what is posted, I see "nodes values are numbers".  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You do not. Identity is not designed to do that - so do not use it and use something you program. Identity is a simple REAL identity, not a "hey, i have some funny business rules I magically want you to follow".

Comment: Fair enough. Is there a way I can do it in MS SQL?

Comment: Yes. That is a separate question though. You asked, got an answer. If you need help understanding SQL progtramming basics - then - ask accordingly. More help about the use case helps - this may be a case where a stored procedure based approach may work best for inserting rows.

Comment: You´re right. Can you elaborate on that? You´re saying that I can do it with Case function, but a Stored procedure would be better?